# matching percentage with mysql

Tags: mysql, algorithm, matching, percentage

I have been trying to create an algorithm with MySQL that returns a list of users that matches an offer and the percentage of the matching. If the users matches the basic main criteria of the offer, they got 70% as a start then if they match some secondary criteria the matching percentage adds up by 2%.

I still don't know how to do it, if you have any idea please enlighten me. Thank you in advance

```
 1. | User    | | Offer    |
 2. |:--------| |:---------|
 3. | city    | | city-lis |
 4. | age     | | age-min  |
 5. | gender  | | gender   |
```

List item

if those criteria meets those users should get 70% as matching percentage than if they meet other criteria the percentage goes up

Comment: To answer this question we need a minimal table stucture of the relevant tables and some example rows.

Comment: you need to add the `Offers` table to the question, and what you've tried so far

Comment: Just to be sure, you have 1 offer you are doing the current search for, and you want to find all users that match one or more criteria of that offer? Then apply a score to the result.

Comment: Yes for a selected offer I need to get list of matched users + their matching percentage with the offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can deduce from your question, this bit of pseudocode might help:

```sql
SELECT username,
  68 +
  ((SELECT city = "example")*2) +
  ((SELECT gender = "m")*2) +
  ((SELECT age > 21)*2) AS score
FROM users
WHERE city = "example" OR gender="m" OR age > 21;
```

#### Explanation

I first select users that match any of the criteria, then I generate a score using subqueries. The `(SELECT gender = "m")` type subqueries will result in `1` if they are true (IE: if gender is m). I then multiply that by 2 to get the preferred score of '2'. If gender does not match 'm' the result will be `0`. And `0 * 2 = 0`. I start out with a score of 68 because you mentioned a starting score of 70 if any field matched. Because all rows in this result will match at least one of these, I substracted 2.

In MySQL you can use SELECT without defining a table to select from. The query `SELECT 1+1` will result in 2. When you use these as subquery you can use the fields in the result for all kinds of tricks. I used them to generate a 1 or 0 for my score result.

Comment: Thank you for response. I don't understand what you mean by  ((SELECT city = "example")*2) ...? Select from where and what's the use of *2

Comment: I have added an explanation